# How do I pull data in one Google Sheet field and have it populate another Google Sheet field?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I pull data in one Google Sheet field and have it populate another Google Sheet field? Also any ideas on how to make a sheet that displays on your website more stylish?

Answer (score 1):

for cell:

```
=A1
```

for range:

```
={A1:A}
```

in another sheet:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

in another spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet"; "Sheet1!A1:A5")
```